# How to combine array items with string substitution?

Tags: bash, text-processing

I'm trying to use Bash string substitution to combine an array. Desired output:

```
cat,dog,fish
```

This works, but isn't there a way to do with without piping?

```
#!/bin/bash

words=(cat dog fish)

echo "${words[@]}" | sed 's/ /,/g'
```

I've been trying this, which doesn't work.

```
echo "${words[@]// /,/}"
```

Comment: @AdminBee , so it's not possible with string substitution?

Comment: Not in the way you suppose, because the individual array elements are the "bare" words without leading or trailing space - there simply is no space that you could substitute with a `,`. You only use spaces when filling the array with a list, to indicate to bash where one element ends and the next one starts. You could just as well have said `declare -A words; words[1]="cat"; words[2]="dog"; words[3]="fish"` and get the same array content.